# Hadoop cluster and MapReduce logic

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new in hadoop development. I read about hadoop cluster structure and understood that there are one namenode, jobtracker, tasktracker and multiple datanodes. 
When we write map-reduce programs we implement mapper and reducer. I also understood logic of these clasess. But I don't understand how are they executed in the hadoop cluster. 
Is mapper executed in the namenode only? 
Is reducer executed seperatly on the datanodes?
I need to make a lot of parralel computations and don't want to use HDFS, how can I be sure that each output collection (from mapper) executes seperatly in all datanodes?
Please explain me the connection between hadoop cluster and map/reduce logic.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Buy a book, read some articles on MR and please post the queries in SO. This is one of the basic query on MR/Hadoop. I have consolidated some MR/Hadoop resources [here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/p/hadoopresources.html) on my blog.

Comment: I've bought and reading "Hadoop in Action", also have read a lot of tutorials/blogs. But I have a problem with understanding relation of map/reduce and cluster architecture. For example: If I write Partitioner and have few reducers, is it guarantees that each reducer executes in datanodes separately? Look, the main problem that I don't want to use hadoop in traditional way (analyze data in DFS), I want run hard computation jobs on the cluster, without big data.

Comment: and I don't need examples of programs here, I need Explanation of Basic hadoop and map/reduce things in few sentences. Sometimes these basic things are very important for learning in future (You are developer and I think you understand what I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map Reduce Jobs are executed by Job Tracker and Task Trackers.

Job Tracker initiates the Job the dividing the input file/files into splits. Tasktrackers are given these splits who run map tasks on the splits( One map task per split). After Mappers throws their output.This output will be passed on the reducer depending on the map output keys . Similar keys are sent to one reducer. Reducer can be more than 1 , depending upon your configuration. Reducer process also runs on one the tasktracker nodes only .

You can see stats of the Job on , jobtracker UI which by default runs on 50030 port.

You can also, visit my website for example topics on Bigdata technologies. Also, you can post your questions , I will try to answer.

http://souravgulati.webs.com/apps/forums/show/14108248-bigdata-learnings-hadoop-hbase-hive-and-other-bigdata-technologies-

Comment: Ok, so as I understand: hadoop isn't what I need (I mean parallel computations)?

Comment: Hadoop gives you parallel computation only . one file gets split and gets processed parallely. 
It can process a very large data set in very small amount of time

Comment: As good conclusion for my answer is that Reducer runs on TaskTrackers parallely and we can control reducers count, thank you for helping.